# How to find critical value in uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

How do you get critical values from uniform distribution p.d.f?? this is the question I got from my teacher

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYs1B.png)

Comment: Please [do not use image for the main part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question.

Answer (score 1):

What is your effort for this question? Why don't you write down the definition of $\alpha$ and work with that?